# Determine whether the number is zero or not without using if else

Tags: java

I want to know how to check the given number is zero or not without using any conditional statements like if else,try catch.

Comment: Please pick *one* language, as it will very likely be very different in the ones you tagged.

Comment: What do you mean by checking without using a conditional? Surely a check is by its nature conditional? That's what check means.

Comment: i want the code in java

Comment: i think we can do with xor or not statements

Comment: We *can* do *something* with bitwise operations, but in the end you'd have to do a conditional...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually I think all three of those languages have an `==` operator.  All OP needs to do is read the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For java, refer to this link, i had the same question and here's where i found the answer. Try this link below, It's using bit-wise operators.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-number-positive-negative-zero-using-bit-operators/

Answer (score -1):

In python, you can use "==" or "!=":

```
def is_number_zero(n):
    return n == 0

>>> is_number_zero(1)
False
>>> is_number_zero(0)
True
```